# Appropriateness of using ～たい in a polite setting: "Have you always wanted to be a teacher" in Japanese

Tags: politeness

I wanted to ask this question to my Japanese instructor, but I understand that in Japanese, it is inappropriate to use 〜たい to 目上の人

So how would I phrase this question in a polite way? よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Can you write up the whole sentence, for reference?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga I was going to say ずっと日本語の先生になりたかったんですか。But from user4092 's post, I realized I can actually make it more polite by asking using と思いました/とお思いでした

Comment: @CeciliaL If you'd like to merge your accounts, see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's inappropriate to confirm what's already done instead of his/her current desire (Actually, this question doesn't seem taken as rude, considering the nature of the question, even if it referred to the current situation). So, I'd say ずっと教師になりたいとお思いでしたか.

Answer (score 0):

You can say ずっと先生になりたいと思われていますか?